# tutorials for ar_pose

Tags: ar-pose

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone. I was looking for a good tutorial to learn how to use ar_pose.
Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56626/tutorials-for-ar_pose/) by [jacky_90](https://answers.ros.org/users/4309/jacky_90/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2013-02-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know, all that exists is the docs on the wiki (http://ros.org/wiki/ar_pose). A somewhat related, but not exactly ar_pose tutorial, is one I built around ar_kinect some time ago: http://ros.org/wiki/mini_max/Tutorials/Grasping%20an%20Object (note, that tutorial is quite old and the code might have changed).

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9591/chao/) on 2014-01-01**:
hi, is the bagfiles in ar_pose opened for public? as i am getting the following error **chao@chao-LIFEBOOK-AH532:~/abc/ar_tools/ar_pose/demo$ ./setup_demos  **
Cloning into 'ar_data'... **
Enter passphrase for key '/home/chao/.ssh/id_rsa':  **
ERROR: Repository not found.  **
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly  **

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2014-01-02**:
See http://answers.ros.org/question/114366/how-to-create-new-data-for-ar_pose/?answer=114571#post-id-114571 for a solution to your problem. In the future, please post a new question, comments don't draw attention as well as new questions.

**Comment by [chao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9591/chao/) on 2014-01-02**:
noted, my apologies. will do it next time. thanks :)